# How to handle exit after being placed by a third party recruiter

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, recruitment, resignation

I placed at a new organization by a third party recruiting agency. During the conversations leading up to the offer, the recruiter told me several times that the work schedule would be 9-5. However, after showing up for the job, I was told that I would be expected to work significantly longer hours, starting earlier in the morning. I discussed with my manager whether it would be possible to transfer to another team with more reasonable hours, and he told me without hesitation that there were no such roles in the organization. When you consider that the pay raise was not so big, I was actually making less per hour than at my previous role, and also being paid at the top of their budget so I could not ask for more. In retrospect, I realize that I should have clarified the hours in the interview and this is my error, but I didn't think much of it given that the recruiter had directly told me that it would be 9-5 so many times as one of the major selling points.

I decided to resign from the position after trying to make myself like it for a month. I did not want to stay too long because they company may have been able to get a refund if I left soon enough, but I do not know the actual fee schedule. During the exit interview, I did not mention the inaccurate information to the company, because I did not think it would be wise to point fingers or throw somebody under the bus. Perhaps this was an honest mistake. I only said that the work-life balance deviated from my expectations.

It occurs to me now though that the company's internal recruiter was giving me a very hostile glare during the exit interview, and that they may have suffered too as a consequence of this mistake. Should I send an email to the internal recruiter informing them of this issue? Also, how should I follow up with the third party recruiter, who almost certainly hates me now?

Answer (score 6):

It's not your fault that the recruiter either gave you bad information, or the company gave the recruiter bad information on work hours. You have no control over what they tell you, you just have to trust what they told you was true, and if it's not true, then you either get it changed(which you tried), or get out of there if it doesn't suit you.

I think the first mistake was not telling the companies manager that you were told specific work hours by the recruiter.  This might feel like you're "pointing fingers" or "throwing him under the bus", but telling them this up front, could have saved a lot of headaches, and could prevent future miscommunication.

If the 3rd party recruiter is upset with you over this kind of issue, maybe they aren't worth working with again, as it's either their fault, which then you shouldn't feel bad, or it's the companies fault for giving the recruiter bad information, so he should be upset at them, not you.

Comment: Because I have not talked to the 3rd party recruiter since leaving, he knows nothing of why I left other than what I told the company. At least until I speak with him, it would seem he has a right to be upset.

Comment: The only way to fix that is to call or email the recruiter and let them know why you quit.  Without being 100% honest about why you were quitting(the hours were different than you were told), you can't expect the recruiter to be real happy with you, but once he finds out that's why, maybe he can adjust on how he gets his information from future employers.

Comment: By not being up front you are setting the scene for this problem to reoccur and that will be bad for everyone.  Maybe the recruiter made an honest mistake, in which case he *needs* to find out that he is giving misinformation.  And the company needs to know why they lost you.  No matter whose fault this major snafu was, it is their responsibility to deal with it and they can't do that unless they know about it.  Don't blame yourself; the company ought to have mentioned the hours, if either party has a non-standard requirement it is their responsibility to bring it up.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're worrying too much, if you want to work with this recruiter just contact them and ask if they have anything for your skill set. If they don't want to work with you or you don't feel they're pushing you because of this then just stop working with them. You haven't done anything wrong in leaving a post that wasn't right for you and I'd be very surprised if this is the recruiters first experience of a client not working out in a role.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** It's just business.

The cost of recruitment is simply one that organisations understand they need to bear.  Sometimes it works out, sometimes it doesn't.  It's actually none of your concern if the organisation has to pay the recruiter, or even if it's refunded.

The old adage holds true, "You must look after yourself *first*".  If the role doesn't fit, then how you were recruited is completely irrelevant.  If the recruiter doesn't want to work with you again, then there are plenty of others out there.  But I will bet money that if another role comes up that fits, they'll come talk to you again :)